# How to change the default text editing app in Quick Look?

Tags: text-editor, textedit, quicklook

I want to customize which app is used to open all *unknown* plain text files from Quick Look. For example, for extension-less `VERSION` file, Quick Look shows **Open with TextEdit**:

[image]

I'd like to make VSCode the default editor for unknown file types.

BTW, to even achieve a textual preview of the `VERSION` file, I had to install https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen.

---

**UPDATE** & solution: This question is indeed closely related to [Replace Text Edit as the default text editor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123833), the problem was that neither of the answers mentioned **public.data** which was necessary for the `VERSION` file in this example. (Without 'public.data', VSCode was offered for `.txt` files but not for extension-less files.)

I've updated [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123954/11926) to that question to include info about 'public.data', in which case this question is really a duplicate of [Replace Text Edit as the default text editor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123833).

Comment: The image you are showing is not of **Preview**, it's: **Quick Look**

Comment: Can you open terminal app and type `mdls` and drag the file you have for quicklook from finder into the terminal window? Editing this to post your file type might help people understand what you need to change.

Comment: @user3439894 That's a great point, I didn't realize that, thank you.

Comment: This qn is closed but is actually asking a different thing to the linked qn. This qn is about changing the app for QuickLook (hitting spacebar in Finder), the linked qn is about changing the default opening app (double clicking in Finder). Please re-open.

Comment: @Robino Please see the "UPDATE & solution" section above.

Comment: @BorekBernard it is possible to have the editor different to the quicklook thumbnailer. This question is about the thumbnailer, the linked question is about the editor. The "UPDATE & solution" implies these are the same thing, which is incorrect. Hence we need to re-open this qn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension-less files are tricky ones for OS to figure out if it is an executable or a text file. I have two README files, one of which is unix executable for some reason and I get a warning if I open it. Another is text file but still recognised as `public.data` as opposed to `public.plain-text`.

```
mdls path/to/file
```

gives you its `kMDItemContentType`. `public.data` files' QuickLook  are generated by

```
/Users/me/Library/QuickLook/QLStephen.qlgenerator
```

Run `qlmanage -m` to get a list.

Unless you can find a QuickLook generator by VSCode, which can preview `public.data` files, you don't have much to do.

I haven't used it, but this seems promising: 
https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen

### OP's response

This worked: `duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode public.data all`

- [Replace Text Edit as the default text editor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123833/replace-text-edit-as-the-default-text-editor/123954#123954)

Comment: Lots of great clues, thanks! I actually have QLStephen installed – otherwise, the OP screenshot would have just a binary icon, not a real text (default behavior of macOS). So if I understand correctly, it's QLStephen that has the power to change "Open with TextEdit" to something different? Could I possibly open a feature request there?

Comment: This is one of the lines in `qlmanage -m` output: `public.data -> /Users/borekb/Library/QuickLook/QLStephen.qlgenerator (1.5.1)`

Comment: This worked  `duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode public.data all`

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on any .txt file on your system.
- Click on 'Get Info'
- Find the *Open With:* section and choose the app you want. (VSCode for this case)
- Finally, click on *Change All* button and you are good to go!

Comment: This answer does not address "to open all plain text files (not specific extensions if possible)" as stated in the OP.

Comment: Yep it's my bad, I just realized that part. Though, I found this topic that might be helpful [make textedit the default app for new file types](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287730/make-textedit-the-default-app-for-new-file-types). Checkout the [Alison E.E](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/203495/alison-e-e)'s answer